# Consuming web api controller action from mvc controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two controllers, one mvc controller and one api controller, both are in the same project.

```
HomeController: Controller{ ... }
DataController: ApiController{ ... }
```

If I want to consume post action in DataController from HomeController is it necessary to use `HttpClient`?

Comment: Why not put the content of the post action into a separate class which both controllers can then use. That way there would be no need to have any network traffic involved, and all the overhead of that.

Answer (score 5):

Not required. You can directly create the object of DataController object in HomeController and use its post method like instance method in .Net.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult GetResult()
        {
            MyApp.DataController dataController = new MyApp.DataController();
            var data = dataController.Post("arguments");

            return View(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Refit that will help you here, it masks all the need for httpclient interaction and allows you to create a service that you can inject into your controllers so you can keep them testable. [Project page for Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit)

Highly recommended this tool.  I've used it quite a bit and think it's part of the essential toolkit when separating logic behind an api.